# For-Loop with positions

Tags: function, for-loop, position, range

Hi guys can someone please explain why my code is printing backwards?

```
s='william'
r=''
for p in range(0,len(s)):
    r=s[p]+r
    print r
```

The outcome looks like:
W

iW

liW

lliW

illiW

ailliW

mailliW

I don't why this program prints this backwards. Can anyone explain how this 'for' program operates?

Comment: Try to use `r=r+s[p]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending r to the end of the string each time.

The first time around:
r = w + ''

The second time around:
r = i + w (in this case w is r from the first iteration)

The third time around:
r = i + iw (r is now iw from the second iteration)

Edit:

This will print william

```
s='william'
r=''
for p in range(0,len(s)):
    r= r + s[p]
    print(r)
```

Comment: Got it Thank you!